# Why does 1|0,2|0 equal 2 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If you evaluate `1|0,2|0` in JavaScript, you'll get `2`.

If you evaluate `1|0+','+2|0`, you'll get `1`.

I cannot make sense of this.

Comment: [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: then why does it return 1 in the second expression?

Comment: That second comma is a string literal, not an operator.

Comment: It's not a syntactic comma in the second expression, it's a comma in a string.

Comment: right, but shouldnot return 1,2 and concatenate the two numbers to the comma?

Comment: Because `|` is low precedence, the second one is equivalent to `(1)|(0+','+2)|(0)` and because `1` is truthy, it stops at that.

Comment: It is a bitwise operation between 1, string and 0, it's like `1|'0,2'|0`, it returns 1

Comment: The comma operator is one of the dark corners of Javascript. I would just avoid.

Comment: Contrast `(1|0)+','+(2|0)`

Comment: Correction to my comment: I conflated bitwise OR `|` with logical OR `||`, so it's not short-cicuiting on truthy `1`. Instead the string `'0,2'` is converted to `0`, and the OR-ing follows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The binary bitwise operators (including `|`) bind less tightly than the addition operator `+`. Thus

```
1|0+','+2|0
```

is really

```
1|(0+','+2)|0
```

which is

```
1|('0,2')|0
```

which is

```
1|0|0
```

which is `1`. (The string "0,2" is converted to an integer; as a *number* it's `NaN`, but because `NaN` is a floating-point concept it turns into `0` when forced to be an integer.)

*edit* — as to the first expression, `1|0,2|0`, that involves the JavaScript comma operator. The comma operator allows a list of separate, essentially independent (other than through side-effects) expressions to be "glued together" into something the parser will recognize as a single expression. When evaluated, each expression will be computed as it normally would be, but the value of the overall expression is just the value of the last one in the list.  Thus, `1|0,2|0` will first cause `1|0` to be evaluated, but that result is thrown away and the overall value is just that of `2|0`.

The comma operator is common to many languages that derive their expression syntax from C. (For all I know, C got it from somewhere else; it's hardly a revolutionary concept.) Because such languages allow for an expression — just **one** expression — to appear in several interesting grammatical situations, and because expressions can (and often do) have side effects, it's sometimes handy to be able to jam several separate expressions into a spot where the language really wants only one. That said, there are often cleaner and better ways to do things. In JavaScript, I would personally prefer to use an immediately-invoked function. It's more typing and probably a little worse for performance reasons, but I think it's a lot cleaner because it allows for an isolated namespace for temporary variables and more involved logic.

Comment: This answer is a good explanation for the second case, but doesn't account for the first case. Can that be added?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure oh sure - I thought the first one was more obvious but probably not for people new to JavaScript and C-like languages.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at an [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to make sense of this.

The expression `1|0,2|0` has bitwise-or at a higher precedence than the comma operator, so it's equivalent to `(1|0), (2|0)`. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates both operands and returns the second one, so you get the value of `(2|0)`. That value is `2`.

The expression `1|0+','+2|0` has addition at a higher precedence than bitwise-or, so it's equivalent to `1|(0+','+2)|0`. The result of `0+','+2` is "0,2", which is not numerical, so it evaluates to `NaN` in numerical operations. It is coerced to `0` in bitwise-or, so that leaves `1|0|0`, and the result of that is 1.

Comment: `"0,2"` is not converted to `0`, it gives `NaN` instead. Try it yourself: `+("0,2")`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens It ends up acting as `0` at least in this operation

Comment: @Ian That's true, but his answer seems to suggest that it evaluates to `0` because it partially parses `"0,2"` (up until the `,`) which is not the case. The `|` forces the `NaN` (the result of making `"0,2"` a `Number`) into a `0`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens It's not my answer. I'm trying to comprehend these answers anyways. I edited my comment to be more what I meant

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Ahhhhhh I see what you're saying now though. I didn't pick up on that in this answer's text, but what you say makes sense and seems right

Comment: @Ian Woops, should check the users more often. But yeah, the answer is a bit misleading. According to his logic, `"1,2"|0` should evaluate to `1` whereas it actually results in `0`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens No problem :) Yeah, I see the problematic text now. It doesn't invalidate the whole answer, just that step. I think they're thinking of `parseInt`, which would do what they're saying, but that's not how strings are converted/coerced into numbers

Comment: Oddly enough, I alternated between two different half-right answers as I typed. First I said it evaluated to `NaN` but assumed that `1|NaN` would evaluate to `NaN`, and that didn't make sense. Then I said it evaluated to `0`. I wasn't aware that `NaN` would sometimes coerce into `0`; clearly I need to look up the rules around that. In the meantime, I'll edit my answer to include the `NaN` value.

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the second operand.

Thus, in `1|0,2|0`, first the two expressions `1|0` and `2|0` are evaluated from left to right and then the result of the last expression (`2|0`) is returned. `1|0 === 1` and `2|0 === 2`, so the result of the last expression is `2` and that's returned.

In `1|0+','+2|0`, the comma appears in a string literal which is concatenated with `0` and `2`. The whole thing is evaluated as followed:

1. `( 1 | ( (0+',')+2 ) ) | 0`
2. `( 1 | ( '0,'+2 ) ) ) | 0` (number + string = string concatenation)
3. `( 1 | '0,2' ) | 0` (string + number = string concatenation)
4. `( 1 | NaN ) | 0` (bitwise OR needs number operands. `0,2` fails to be converted, giving `NaN` instead)
5. `1 | 0` (bitwise OR only deals with integers, so the floating-point `NaN` is cast to `0`)
6. `1`